# getLibraryDirectory not working for desktop app

Tags: database, flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, plug

i'm working on Flutter desktop application and got stuck at a point. I want to create local database for data storage. I'm using path_provider plugin to get path of directory for saving database file. the function getLibraryDirectory() not working in my application. I debug my application also at the point of creation of database this function throw exception "UnimplementedError: getLibraryPath() has not been implemented".

This is the plugin i am using. https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider

Anyone help me out there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into the package's sources and there is no implementation for the method `getLibraryDirectory()` on Windows and Linux as the property `getLibraryPath()` needed to call this method has not been implemented either. Based on the source `getLibraryDirectory()` seems implemented on [MacOS](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/path_provider/path_provider_macos/macos/Classes/PathProviderPlugin.swift#L40) only.

Here are the methods that should be implemented for **Windows and Linux**:

- `getTemporaryDirectory()`
- `getApplicationSupportDirectory()`
- `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`
- `getDownloadsDirectory()`

And one more for **Windows only**:

- `getPath(String folderID) // Retrieve any known folder from Windows.`

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me why the build exe file of flutter desktop application not returning path of directory when run on another desktop. I am using getApplicationSupportDirectory() this method to get the path of directory for saving database file but it is not returning any path. Code is working fine on my desktop when i run the application. What can be the issue?

Comment: Honestly I won't be able to tell without any code sample, but this would then be another question to open if you want a complete answer.